# Is partition table type "loop" a good or bad idea on BTRFS?

Tags: partition, hard-disk, btrfs

I have started to convert my disks to `btrfs` and following tutorials, and most of them created the filesystem directly on the device instead on a partition.

The file system is working and stores data but what is the downside of partition table type named `loop`?
Based on the `man` page, `loop` is raw device access, but are there downsides compared to `GPT` or `MBR`?

I have a few TB to move to the new disks and do not want to do this over and over again to change the partition type.

Comment: Could you add the command you used to create the btrfs filesystem to your question? How many disks? RAID?

Comment: I used `mkfs.btrfs /dev/sdd` which made the trick and all is working fine for the moment

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`loop` isn't a partition table - you haven't got one of those on a whole disk filesystem.  Whatever you are using that's showing you `loop` may be doing this because it can't find a partition table.  Apparently `parted` on a `LVM` setup does this.

If these drives are not the ones you use to boot then there is no issue with installing a filesystem on the whole drive (as opposed to a partition).  In fact, you can do that using other filesystems other than `btrfs` - partitions are only useful if you need to partition disks into multiple filesystems.

Of course, if you're uncertain, simply create a `GPT` partition table regardless.  The few kilobytes needed for this aren't really going to create a big dent in your huge 1TiB disk.  Doing this will also give you the usual `/dev/sda1` partition name for your filesystem as opposed to `/dev/sda` (no partition number) for  a full-disk filesystem.  There may (no guarantee) be a few utilities out there that will complain with the latter format and using the former will remove that possibility.

There are a few articles on the Internet on booting from a un-partitioned disk.  While this may be possible, you'll probably struggle to get support - especially the free type on forums/U&L etc - if you try such an edge case setup.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I case creating GPT on my 3TB disks on linux was/is always a little of a hazzle but using the disks without a partition works just fine.

I am only using these disks for data storage on my server, the boot device is a different one only having the OS on it.

In this case, I am using btrfs on the loop/raw HDD now, thanks for the clarification.